# ms access button on a form not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database with many forms, when I added a button with an onClick event to one of them it just doesn't work. The onClick event code is very simple:

```
Private Sub button_Click()
  DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Doesn't matter how I click it, the event is not firing. I put a break point in front of the sub, and realized that when I clicked the button the event is not even firing. I create buttons in other forms they work fine, its just this one specific form that doesn't work.

I did some testing, and realized that when I make the form into a split form, the button stops working.

Any Idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Right click on the button and select "Properties". "On Click" should indicate "[Event Procedure]". Also make sure the button name matches on the sub.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wrote the code by click the Event Procedure selection for onClick event. It seems like this problem only happens in split form. Because I change the form property to any other kind of form it works fine. However I have another split form with all the buttons working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm..it seems like there has to be at least one field in the split form for the button to work. Did not know that before

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe the function is not linked to the button.

- did you checked that in the button properties "on click" has the vba function linked?
- the buttom name and the function im vba are the same? "Button"?

Answer (score 0):

The Command Button Wizard create a command button that performs a specific task. In an Access (.accdb) file, the wizard creates a macro that is embedded in the OnClick property of the command button. In an .mdb or .adp file, the wizard creates VBA code, because embedded macros are not available in those file formats.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite relevant to your question but might help someone else in the future where an event is not firing....I had a similar issue in an Excel form where an event was supposed to happen when I click a button...I deleted the button and added it again and it worked...could be a bug or a file corruption...try deleting then adding the control again.